# How to find if groups are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have these three groups and I was wondering if they were isomorphic to each other?
$$a)\space \mathbb{Z}_{60}\space b)\space \mathbb{Z}_{6} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \space c)\space\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$$

So first I know that c) is isomorphic to a)  because gcd(2,2,15)=1 so it is cyclic and the order of both of them is $60$, however I am not sure how to go further with the relationship with the rest of them? Can anyone show me how! Cheers

Comment: The last group is *not* cyclic: you can check for yourself that every node has an order that divides 30. (That is $30g = 0$ or $g^{30} = 1$, depending on if you write the group additively or multiplicatively.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $\mathbb Z_6\times\mathbb Z_{10}$ and $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_{15}$ are isomorphic (and none of them is cyclic), since both of them are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_5$.

On the other hand, $\mathbb Z_{60}$ has an element whose order is $60$ (that is, it is a cyclic group), whereas none of the other two has such an element. Therefore, $\mathbb Z_{60}$ is not isomorphic to any of the other two.

Comment: How are b,c cyclic like that is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Since I wrote that they are **not** cyclic, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how are they both isomorphic?

Comment: If $m,n\in\mathbb N$ are co-prime, then $\mathbb Z_{mn}\simeq\mathbb Z_m\times\mathbb Z_n$. So,\begin{align}\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_5&\simeq\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_5\\&\simeq\mathbb Z_6\times\mathbb Z_{10}\end{align}and, by a similar argument,$$\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_5\simeq\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_{15}.$$